# Shift Right (srl) going wrong on VHDL Quartus II

Tags: vhdl, bit-shift, quartus

I'm trying to make a 8-bit Sequential Multiplier on Quartus II. I did all the simulations of all blocks, but one is showing error on the VWF simulation. The `sum_reg` block it's doing a infinite shift in a very small time interval.

[image]

In the "dark blue" part of waveform simulation, on o_DOUT, it's when the shift gones infinite until the MSB goes to the LSB. The image below shows what happens in the dark blue part of the simulation:

[image]

Someone know what's happen?

Below the code:

Sum register(where the simulation goes wrong):

```
 library IEEE;
 use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
 use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

 entity sum_register is 
 port (
     i_DIN   : in UNSIGNED(8 DOWNTO 0);
     i_LOAD  : in STD_LOGIC;
     i_CLEAR : in STD_LOGIC;
     i_SHIFT : in STD_LOGIC;
     o_DOUT  : buffer UNSIGNED(15 downto 0)
 );
 end sum_register;

 architecture arch_1 of sum_register is 
 begin 
     process(i_CLEAR,i_LOAD,i_SHIFT, i_DIN)
     begin
        IF (i_CLEAR = '1') THEN
            o_DOUT <= "0000000000000000";
        ELSIF (i_LOAD = '1') THEN
            o_DOUT(15 downto 7) <= i_DIN;
        ELSIF (i_SHIFT = '1') THEN
             o_DOUT <= o_DOUT SRL 1;
        END IF;
      end process;
end arch_1;
```

Comment: Please consider making a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I've edited the original publication to make the MVE, better now! Thanks!

Comment: That's still not an [MCVE], ***Make sure all information necessary to reproduce the problem is included**.  You also neglected to inform your reading audience this is a post synthesis simulation, a [behavioral simulation](http://i.stack.imgur.com/oRk4Z.png) shows no problem. It's a striking oscillator, feeding output back to input with delay through the implementation of srl, i_SHIFT is a latch enable for o_DOUT.  A behavioral simulation would fail if you had o_DOUT in the process sensitivity list.

Comment: user1155120, so should I put a delay after the shift, something like:  o_DOUT <= o_DOUT SRL 1 after "xx" ns;? Or should I put the output signal out of the process? I don't fully understood your answer.

Comment: I used a clock signal to solve the problem, I made this circuit synchronous to solve the latch problem. But I am really interested to understand your solution, because It's the second time that i have this problem, and again, I need to use a clock signal to solve this, If you could explain detailed  again your solution without a clock signal I'll be very grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a clock signal in the circuit to make this synchronous, you will need an input in your entity like this:

```
i_CLOCK : in STD_ULOGIC;
```

After this you will need to make your process sensitivy to the clock:

```
process(i_CLOCK)
```

And your architecture will change to this:

```
 architecture arch_1 of sum_register is
  SIGNAL r_DOUT : unsigned(15 downto 0);
 begin
     process(i_CLOCK)
     begin
     IF rising_edge(i_CLOCK) THEN
        IF (i_CLEAR = '1') THEN
            r_DOUT <= "0000000000000000";
        ELSIF (i_LOAD = '1') THEN
            r_DOUT(15 downto 8) <= i_DIN;
        ELSIF (i_SHIFT = '1') THEN
              r_DOUT <= r_DOUT SRL 1;
        END IF;
      END IF;
      end process;
      o_DOUT <= r_DOUT;
end arch_1;
```

With this architecture you will need a unsigned signal to make atribution for your output o_DOUT, with this you can change your o_DOUT output to output type again (not buffer).

NOTE: The clock signal needs to be the same for all blocks!